# What is the difference between base.html.twig and single-cms-page.html.twig?

Tags: twig, shopware

The theme I currently deal with has two pretty similar files: `/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig` and `/httpdocs/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/content/single-cms-page.html.twig`.

Both seem to render the whole source code: `<HTML><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`, with some differences in the content of single blocks.

They both don't seem to extend each other - `single-cms-page.html.twig` hasn't `{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}` and vice versa.

**Q**: In which cases frontend is rendered by `base.html.twig` and in which - `single-cms-page.html.twig`. Could somebody explain this? What is the sense of having these two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`single-cms-page.html.twig` seems to be used only for the Maintenance page, in `\Shopware\Storefront\Controller\MaintenanceController::renderSinglePage` it's more stripped-down and avoids accidentially rendering things other modules put into `base.html.twig`'s blocks on the Maintenance page.